# Can't redirect 404, 403 and 401 to custom pages (loader.php)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

#Uncomment following lines if you 
want to use image caching!
#<IfModule mod_expires.c>
#  ExpiresActive On
#  ExpiresDefault A1209600
#  ExpiresByType text/html A1
#</IfModule>

# Uncomment following lines if Apache doesnt support MultiViews!
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Uncomment the 2 lines below if you are using www.domain.com
# as the baseurl for the site and users access your site 
# via domain.com (THIS IS REQUIRED FOR JQUERY TO WORK)

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^todotirantes.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.todotirantes.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* loader.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# Edit below lines and set to
# ErrorDocument CODE /RELATIVE/error.php
# If the script is installed in the default document
# root then relative is null.
ErrorDocument 401 /index.php
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

And this loader.php

```
<?php
//die('Only enable this script if you dont have support for MultiViews');
    $relative = '';
$loaders  = array(
    'ajax' => 1,
    'album' => 1,
    'albums' => 1,
    'blog' => 1,
    'blogs' => 1,
    'captcha' => 1,
    'categories' => 1,
    'community' => 1,
    'confirm' => 1,
    'notfound' => 1,
    'feedback' => 1,
    'feeds' => 1,
    'game' => 1,
    'games' => 1,
    'index' => 1,
    'invite' => 1,
    'loader' => 1,
    'login' => 1,
    'logout' => 1,
    'lost' => 1,
    'mail' => 1,
    'notice' => 1,
    'notices' => 1,
    'photo' => 1,
    'requests' => 1,
    'search' => 1,
    'signup' => 1,
    'static' => 1,
    'stream' => 1,
    'upload' => 1,
    'user' => 1,
    'users' => 1,
    'video' => 1,
    'videos' => 1,
    'edit' => 1,
    'embed' => 1,
    'view' => 1,    
    'ads' => 1
);

$query      = ( isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ) ? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : NULL;
$request    = str_replace($relative, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$request    = str_replace('?' .$query, '', $request);
$request    = explode('/', trim($request, '/'));
if (isset($request['0'])) {
    $page   = $request['0'];
    if (isset($loaders[$page])) {
        require $page. '.php';
    } else {
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
        die();
    }
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    die();
}
?>
```

The problem is the RewriteRule of loader.php.
If the error it's 404/401 or 403, it's not working and it redirects to a Google error page:

```
No se puede encontrar esta página (platanoporno.xxx)
No se ha encontrado ninguna página web para la dirección 
https://platanoporno.xxx/hshsj.
HTTP ERROR 404
```

I want to redirect all 404/403/401 to /notfound/video_missing
Will it be possible?
I tried to change some code, in the loader PHP and in the htaccess but didn't work...

EDIT:
It's an adult page, if you are +18 you can test how the website acts with 404.
If you type https://platanoporno.xxx/usuxjwiw for example (change usuxjwiw with another random word) it throws Google error 404 page.
If you type https://platanoporno.xxx/videos/usuxjwiw It redirects to a 404 but in this case it's covered by the CMS.
The CMS is AdultVideoScript.com

Comment: "Google error page"? Where is your site hosted? The `ErrorDocument` directives are commented out in your `.htaccess` file, but they also reference `index.php`, not `loader.php`? How are the 401 and 403 responses being triggered? If they are triggered by your application then setting the `ErrorDocument` is not going to help. You don't appear to have a route set for `/notfound/video_missing`, jut for `notfound`? "I tried to change some code" - a bit vague.

Comment: Hi @MrWhite let me explain it further. Google error page I mean: "No se puede encontrar esta página (platanoporno.xxx)No se ha encontrado ninguna página web para la dirección https://platanoporno.xxx/hshsj.
HTTP ERROR 404". About the commented code, it doesn't work if I outcomment it.

Comment: About the notfound.php it does not work with platanoporno.xxx/notfound.php or /notfound/ I don't know why

Comment: Trying to specify `ErrorDocument 404` is pointless with this kind of routing setup. _Every_ requested URL that does not match an existing file or folder, will be rewritten to the loader.php - so from the web server’s point of view, there will be no 404s any more, ever. It is the job of your application now to decide, whether it has content to serve for the request URL - or whether it will answer with a 404 response itself now. 401/403 can be a different story, but that depends on how they are triggered - by the web server itself, or again, internally by your application.